# '80s comic book featuring a homicidal pink fairy

Tags: story-identification, comics

I would like some help identifying a comic book that I read many years ago, and which I've been curious about ever since.

See, in 1988 I was in the hospital, and being 11 at the time, I spent some time in a "children's area". They had a bunch of books to read, and a few comic books. **One of the books featured a rather grim story about a "fairy", a character dressed in a pink(?) dress with fairy wings, who would appear to people and then kill them out of "mercy" or something.** Like, she tossed a radio into a guy's bathtub, electrocuting him; of course this made it look like an accident. The wings appeared as part of a costume, I think. However, the character was also portrayed as having supernatural powers, like appearing out of thin air, and also hovering.

For the longest time, I *thought* this was a back-up storyline in *Dr. Fate Annual #1*, because I remember reading that book in the hospital, but then I tracked it down and it doesn't have the "fairy" story. (That book is the story about Eric and Linda finding Eric's father on the spiritual plane.) I also remember reading *The One #1* by Rick Veitch at the time, but that doesn't have it either. (Yeah, I read *Dr. Fate* and *The One* at 11, I guess I was precocious! And desperately bored.)

My feeling was that this was a storyline introducing a new villain who would face the hero one or two issues later. I remember the comic looking "modern" at the time, so it was probably 80s? It might have been a hero book, like...I don't know, *Batman*? *Punisher*? *Dr. Strange*?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall if the "fairy" character's wings were part of their body, or part of a costume? Trying to determine if this character was actually superhuman/inhuman in some way, or just an oddly dressed human with a homicidal streak.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Thank you! The wings appeared part of a costume, I think. *However,* the character was also portrayed as having supernatural powers, like appearing out of thin air, and also hovering.

Comment: @JohnEvans could you please [edit] that into your question?